# In ActiveReportsJS is it possible to pass parameters to a Web Service?

Tags: activereports

I have a report which data source is a Web Service API, the API requires some parameters and I want to pass them in the "Content URI" property of the data source.

Is it possible to assign parameters to the Content URI?

Note: when I write something like

```
jsondoc=http:\localhost:3480\resource.json?param1=&Parameters!Data.Value
```

The URI is automatically changed to

```
..\..\..\..\applications\ActiveReportsJS_Designer\jsondoc=http:\localhost:3480\resource.json?param1=&Parameters!Data.Value
```

and it is not possible to load the data source from the Web Service

Reference: https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsjs/docs/v1/DeveloperGuide/ActiveReportsJSViewer/Features

[image: ActiveReportsJS DataSource]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are steps that are currently to be used for parametrized web-service requests as a report's data source:

- Start with the static URI, for example `jsondoc=http:\localhost:3480\resource.json?param1=&Parameters!Data.Value`
- Add the data set, fill out the [JSON path](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to obtain the fields list.
- Modify the data source URI so that it looks like `="jsondoc=http:\localhost:3480\resource.json?param1=" & Parameters!Data.Value`  - this the expression that evaluated at runtime based on the parameter's value.

Comment: Thank you, the following link is for the support ticket at GrapeCity. https://www.grapecity.com/forums/activereportsjs/is-it-possible-to-pass-par